# String-Formatting - Generate a table based on the contents of Two Maps and print it on the Console

Tags: java, string, collections, hashmap, string-formatting

What is the possible way to combine two Maps in order to generate a table (i.e. to render the below table on console using `System.out`) filled with the entries of these maps?

```
Map<String, Long> sourceMap = new HashMap<String,Long>();
sourceMap.put("Class1",10);
sourceMap.put("Class2,"20);
sourceMap.put("Class3,"30);

Map<String, Long> targetMap = new HashMap<String,Long>();
targetMap.put("Class1",10);
targetMap.put("Class4,"20);
```

*A table-sample:*

[image]

***Note:*** in this example, there's no specific reason for `Class2` and `Class4` to be displayed on the same line.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Thanks for replying, yes like a java type such as List to store each row as an object.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko The table structure needs to be displayed on java console as output.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko The intention is to clearly distinguish two maps data, there is no condition to store them in a list.

Comment: @Holger No specific reason, but Class2 belongs to source map and Class4 belongs to the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a `Set` of Entries from each `Map` and iterate over both sets simultaneously, printing entries from both as formatted as a single line of text.

The rest boils down to [`System.out.printf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) and [*basic formatting*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html).

***Note:** that if the order of entries is important, you need to use a `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`*.

That's how an implementation encapsulated into a separate class might look like:

```
public class TablePrinter {
    
    public static final String SOURCE_TITLE = "SourceMap";
    public static final String TARGET_TITLE = "TargetMap";
    
    private String horizontalBorder;
    private String verticalBorder;
    private int columnWidth;
    
    public TablePrinter(String horizontalBorder, String verticalBorder, int columnWidth) {
        this.horizontalBorder = horizontalBorder;
        this.verticalBorder = verticalBorder;
        this.columnWidth = columnWidth;
    }
    
    public void printTable(Map<String, Long> source,
                           Map<String, Long> target) {
        
        printHorizontalLine();
        
        printHeader();
        
        printHorizontalLine();
        
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Long>> sourceEntries = source.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Long>> targetEntries = target.entrySet().iterator();
        
        while (sourceEntries.hasNext() || targetEntries.hasNext()) {
            
            String k1 = "";
            String v1 = "";
            String k2 = "";
            String v2 = "";
            
            if (sourceEntries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Long> entry = sourceEntries.next();
                k1 = entry.getKey();
                v1 = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
            }
            if (targetEntries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Long> entry = targetEntries.next();
                k2 = entry.getKey();
                v2 = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
            }
            
            printRow(k1, v1, k2, v2);
            printHorizontalLine();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Each column name would be printed in the center of column.
     * The width of the header-row is guaranteed to be equal to the width of the regular row
     */
    public void printHeader() {
        
        int halfTableWidth = 2 * columnWidth + 1; // -> "left column | right column" <-
        
        int leftPadding1 = halfTableWidth / 2 - SOURCE_TITLE.length() / 2;
        int rightPadding1 = halfTableWidth - leftPadding1 - SOURCE_TITLE.length();
        int leftPadding2 = halfTableWidth / 2 - TARGET_TITLE.length() / 2;
        int rightPadding2 = halfTableWidth - leftPadding2 - TARGET_TITLE.length();
        
        String format = getHeaderFormat(leftPadding1, rightPadding1, leftPadding2, rightPadding2);
        
        System.out.printf(format, "", SOURCE_TITLE, "", "", TARGET_TITLE, "");
    }
    
    public String getHeaderFormat(int leftPadding1, int rightPadding1,
                                  int leftPadding2, int rightPadding2) {
        
        String leftSection = "%" + leftPadding1 + "s%s%" + rightPadding1 + "s";
        String rightSection = "%" + leftPadding2 + "s%s%" + rightPadding2 + "s";
        
        return verticalBorder + leftSection + verticalBorder + rightSection + verticalBorder + "\n";
    }
    
    public void printRow(String k1, String v1, String k2, String v2) {
        
        System.out.printf(getRowFormat(columnWidth), k1, v1, k2, v2);
    }
    
    public String getRowFormat(int columnWidth) {
        
        String section = " %-" + (columnWidth - 1) + "s"; // because of the white space on the left 1 was subtracted
        
        String format = Stream.generate(() -> section).limit(4) // same as `tableBorder + section + tableBorder + section + tableBorder` two times `+ "\n"`
            .collect(Collectors.joining(verticalBorder, verticalBorder, verticalBorder));
        
        return format + "\n";
    }
    
    public void printHorizontalLine() {
        
        int tableWidth = 4 * columnWidth + 5;
        
        System.out.println(horizontalBorder.repeat(tableWidth));
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initializing maps
    Map<String, Long> sourceMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    sourceMap.put("Class1", 10L);
    sourceMap.put("Class2", 20L);
    sourceMap.put("Class3", 30L);
    
    Map<String, Long> targetMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    targetMap.put("Class1", 10L);
    targetMap.put("Class4", 20L);

    // printing maps
    TablePrinter printer = new TablePrinter("-", "|", 10);

    printer.printTable(sourceMap, targetMap);
}
```

*Output:*

```
---------------------------------------------
|      SourceMap      |      TargetMap      |
---------------------------------------------
| Class1   | 10       | Class1   | 10       |
---------------------------------------------
| Class2   | 20       | Class4   | 20       |
---------------------------------------------
| Class3   | 30       |          |          |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @Holger You're right, that simple. The genuine answer: I've started with a couple of hard-coded formats and then made this thing a bit more flexible, `String.format()` remained as a leftover. Fixed that undercooked stuff.